# IIS 5.1 and classic ASP "The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden."

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I know a similar question was raised on this in 2009, but I am really baffled by this.

I have a Windows XP development machine which is used for maintenance on a classic ASP web application.  IIS 5.1 is the web server.

The problem: some sites serve up classic ASP with no problem, other sites give the "The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be incorrect. " error in a ASP.Net looking way.  Suggesting that asp.dll isn't being used to serve up the pages!?  The list of which dll to use with which file extension is the same for both sites.  Any new site created appears to have the same issue with serving cASP.

If IIS was consistently failing to server cASP on all sites I would be looking at common configuration, but as it's working on a some and not others I am utterly baffled.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And what is the code of the default page? What's different in the code between site that works and one that doesn't?

Comment: That's just it, there is no difference in the code base between a site that works and one that doesn't.  Suggesting there is some setting in IIS forcing asp.net to be expected (ie. asp.dll is not being used)

Comment: How the sites are defined? Does each has its own port and application pool, or are they all virtual sites under the same root?

Comment: All under Default WebSite, it's very odd..